# Missing hashes in .git object folder

Tags: git, github

I was going through the internal of how git works. I was reading that git stores everything in objects folder. It first make SHA1 hash of file and stores it in Object folder. I tried the following commands on 1 of my repository, but i couldn't find the hash file in the objects directory but using `cat-file` command, i am able to see the command. Is there something i am missing. Below are the steps are i did to understand.

I did git log to find the latest commit,

[image]

then i cat-file the mentioned commit id and can see the hash of tree file.

[image]

If i go to objects folder and search for the folder with 1st two characters of the hash, i am not able to find the folder.

[image]

But still i am able to get the file.

[image]

I tried it for files (blob) also from the cat-file of tree, but couldn't find the files with hash in objects folder. Can anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take a look at :

```
.git/objects/pack
```

… too.

Git indeed use the object system you describe but eventually, when there's too many of them, Git will put the garbage collector in charge of **packing** them, that is gathering some of them then concatenating them into a single file (without compressing, though, since objects are already compressed. They're therefore directly accessible in the middle of pack file). Aside of this, an index file "***.idx**" is created too in order to quickly retrieve them.

This both scavenges useful inodes and space remaining at the end of each file's last block on the filesystem, but the operation takes time and ressources. That's why Git will trigger this operation only at certain times.

See: [Git Internals: Pack Files](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles).

Comment: Can you tell me what and how exactly to look in pack folder. I can see a bunch of files *.idx and *.pack files. But how to relate a file to the above mentioned commit id? because i cannot see any file by the commit id hash or tree hash.

Comment: **"*.pack"** is the name of packed file (containing a bunch of regular objects, just like an archive). **"*.idx"** is the associated index file, named after it (same name, different extension). You access these objects just like the regular ones: it's transparent from Git's command line. If however you're interested in the way they're built, follow the link to documentation I've just added to my post above.

Comment: Just a side note: objects in pack files are both compressed like unpacked objects, *and* delta-encoded (against the decompressed copies of each other). The delta compression is the part that burns the most CPU time as Git must spend a lot of effort finding objects that compress well against each other and choosing a delta chain order and length that results in good compression.